# define string structure for deserialize json object nested

Tags: c#

this is the json file:

```
    {
  "Message": {
    "Code": 200,
    "Message": "request success"
  },
  "Data": {
    "USD": {
      "Jual": "13780",
      "Beli": "13760"
    }
  },
  "LastUpdate": "2015-11-27 22:00:11",
  "ProcessingTime": 0.0794281959534
}
```

I have a problem when I am converting to class like this:

```
        public class Message
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public class USD
    {
        public string Jual { get; set; }
        public string Beli { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {


   public USD USD { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Message Message { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdate { get; set; }
    public double ProcessingTime { get; set; }
}
```

and when I deserialized with this code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            var json = wc.DownloadString(textBox1.Text);

            List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = json;
        }
```

When I run the code I get an unhandled exception which says:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WindowsFormApp.EmployeeInfo+Areas]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.”
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to get the last item deserialized correctly?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Can you please explain what part of error message you did not understand?

Answer (score 1):

JSON.Net is expecting (when you pass a collection type to the `DeserializeObject` method), that the root object is an array. According to your data, it's an object and needs to be processed as a singular user.

And then you need to pass that to the dataSource, so you'd then wrap the deserialized `User` into `var userList = new List<User>{user};`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty straightforward. You are trying to deserialize something that isn't an array (your JSON string) into a collection (`List<User>`). It's not a collection so you can't do that. You should be doing something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json)` to get a single object.